# Compile java classes protobuf

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I am having trouble with compiling the AddPerson.java class for the Protubuf tutorial on Google while following a youtube video link below at 5:09. I keep getting addperson command not found[image]
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BJqSDvCZcx8&t=312s

This is the command that I used.

```
java -cp protobuf-java-3.5.1.jar; AddPerson addressbook.data
```

I'm currently on Ubuntu linux running the command in the terminal. I have a feeling the command might need to be slightly tweak for linux as the op of the video is using Windows with the command prompt.

Comment: Those look like two different commands, separated by a semicolon.  Try executing each of them on their own separate command line.

Comment: More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/----command-separator-

Comment: If that doesn't work, look for an `AddPerson.exe` in your current folder.  If it's not there, that's probably why this isn't working.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I would think that Linux wouldn't be able to utilize a .exe file... or I may be wrong

Comment: Ah so there's that much difference.  Might be time to start looking for a Linux-specific tutorial.

Comment: I do agree with Mr. Harvey that it may be difficult to follow this tutorial using Ubuntu, but you might be able to do something gimmickey with WINE in order to get this to work

Comment: Actually, @axesspwns are you trying to compile a .java file, or run a .class? As far as I am aware, you would need to use to javac command to compile java programs instead of java, which is used to execute .jar and .class files

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223218/discussion-between-spyre-and-robert-harvey).

Comment: @RobertHarvey added an answer post that solved my issue

Comment: @Spyre added an answer post that solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

After more research, you use .: before the name of .jar file instead of the semicolon at the end.

```
java -cp .:protobuf-java-3.5.1.jar AddPerson addressbook.data
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two distinct problems.

1. Since you are running on Linux, the class path separator is `:` rather than `;` as shown in the video.
2. You need to include the JAR file or directory containing >>your<< code on the classpath.  I expect that the video actually did this using the `.` character.  Remember that on Windows AND Linux, `.` means "the current directory".

So you should be running the command on Linux like this:

```
$ java -cp .:protobuf-java-3.5.1.jar AddPerson addressbook.data
```

<sup>This assumes that your `AddPerson` class does not have a `package` declaration, and that `AddPerson.class` is in the current directory.  It gets a bit more complicated if packages are involved.</sup>

Note that I put `.` in front of `protobuf-java-3.5.1.jar` on the classpath.  It probably doesn't matter in this case, but in general the order does matter.  The classloader searches for classes in a specific order<sup>1</sup>.

- first, the system classpath where the standard library classes live
- then, the Java installation's Extensions directory<sup>2</sup>
- finally, the locations in the application's classpath ... in the order that they are specified on the classpath.

The first one class with the correct (fully qualified) name that it finds will "win".  So if your classpath was `-cp protobuf-java-3.5.1.jar:.` and there just happened to be<sup>3</sup> an `AddPerson` class in `protobuf-java-3.5.1.jar`, then *that* would be loaded in preference to your class.

---

<sup>1 - This can be further tweaked by the application itself creating classloaders at runtime.  But that is a different topic.

2 - For Java 8 and earlier.  Support for the "extensions" mechanism was dropped in Java 9.

3 - Don't worry, there isn't.  But the point is that the classpath order **can** matter.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

When you want to run a java console app or other *.jar file with help of external jar file . This the procedure ,

#### In Linux Environment

#### compile

`javac -cp .:/home/user/ess_jar_files/protobuf-java-3.5.1.jar AddPerson.java`

#### run

`java -cp .:/home/user/ess_jar_files/protobuf-java-3.5.1.jar AddPerson addressbook.data`

#### In Windows Environment

#### compile

`javac -cp .;D:\essential_jars\protobuf-java-3.5.1.jar AddPerson.java`

#### run

`java -cp .;D:\essential_jars\protobuf-java-3.5.1.jar AddPerson addressbook.data`